# Does Spring Cloud Gateway support Rsocket for load-balancing?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-gateway, rsocket

I'm implementing a microservices system with Spring Boot, and I want to have a service that using Rsocket to make real-time connecting between user and system. But in the document of Spring Cloud Gateway, that's seem not support Rsocket. Is this possible to using Rsocket in a microservices system with Spring Boot ? Or should I using websocket instead ?

Here is my idea

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Don't try this, lost time. See authoritative article

- https://spring.io/blog/2020/03/25/spring-tips-spring-cloud-loadbalancer
- https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-cloud-loadbalancer/
- https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/reference/html/#the-websocket-routing-filter
- https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/reference/html/#the-loadbalancerclient-filter
- https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/reference/html/#reactive-loadbalancer-client-filter

For load balancing with Spring Cloud Gateway, let use technology stack [Eureka Discovery Client + Cloud Loadbalancer + Reactive Web] or Ribbon (Netflix Open Source Software - Netflix OSS).

Rsocket for "... Reactive Streams", load balancing need something like request/response round robin, these are different.

Comment: Hey guys, I want to scale horiziontal ther service realtime.